# SQL ALCHEMY - Query a for a child on a condition specified in a parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am building a slightly unconventional marketplace in flask, the requirements mean that the price of products varies depending on parameters specified by the user.

The user enters details -> the site creates a quote -> when a user decides to purchase, an order is created (which is linked to the quote).

[image]

I am building a page where merchants (who are selling through the site) can view their orders (so they can fulfill them). The issue I am now faced with is that the merchantID is specified in the Product, and I do not think the filter_by is up to the task.

```
class Quote(db.Model):
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      ...
      order = db.relationship('Order', backref='quote', lazy=True)


class Product(db.Model):
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      ...
      product = db.relationship('Quote', backref='product', lazy=True)
```

```
g.merchant.id = current_merchant()

orders = Order.query.filter_by(Order.quote.product.merchantID == g.merchant.id).all()
```

To get the orders for a merchant, I need to filter the orders by the merchantID that exists in the Product, related to the Quote which is finally related to the Order.

I am wondering if there is an elegant way of querying for a child based on a condition specified on its parent.

I considered this briefly:

```
orders = Order.query.all()
my_orders = []
for order in orders:
      if order.quote.product.merchantID == g.merchant.id:
            my_orders.append(order)
```

But my ugly code senses are tingling (perhaps wrongly); I just suspect there is a better way around this problem.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Matt Healy's answer on this question [SQL Alchemy query child table filtered by parent join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765323/sql-alchemy-query-child-table-filtered-by-parent-join?rq=1)

```
Orders = Order.query.join(Quote).join(Product).filter(Product.merchantID == g.merchant.id).all()
```

Works.